# Is it possible to send an SQL query condition as an argument to a function in RoR?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
condition = "status = #{val} OR quality = #{other_val}"

def func(condition)
   Table.where(condition).other_queries
end
```

I need this function because other_queries is used commonly and I don't want to repeat code.

The problem is that when `val` or `other_val` is empty, I get an invalid SQL error. The query string basically looks like  `"status = OR quality = 4"`

What do I do in this case?

Comment: What is the error.. Please paste it.

Comment: Where will `val` and `other_val` set? Globally or in `func`?

Comment: it will set by the function calling func()

Comment: In the example above you are passing a string as a parameter. Passing a string as a parameter is allowed in ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa - yes I am, what else is possible?

Comment: I just answered the question, asked in the title :) Will write an answer, sec.

Comment: You need to explain (in your question) what you **want** to happen if `val` or `other_val` are blank.

Comment: Besides multiple answered questions here on SO, that’s the good article on the topic: http://zargony.com/2008/06/08/activerecord-condition-building-made-easy

Comment: You need an extra condition for both to either not add the condition at all, or change it to IS NULL instead of = #{val}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
condition = []
condition << "status = #{val}" if val
condition << "quality = #{other_val}" if other_val

def func(condition)
   (condition.empty? ? Table : Table.where(condition.join(' OR '))).other_queries
end
```